# True USB 3.0 crossover switch

Tags: usb, switch

I’m looking for a TRUE usb 3.0 crossover switch.. I know there are peripheral switches which take 1 input and share peripherals on the other side. What I’m looking for is a path selector where I have 2 usb cables coming in InA and InB and two going out, outA and outB. When I switch I want cable inA to be routed to outB and cable inB to be routed to outA. Then when I switch again, I want inA to be routed to outA and inB to be routed to outB.

I hope this makes sense...what I’m trying to do is switch two laptops between two different port replicators at the click of a button.

Comment: What are you switching between these laptops? It's a bit of a weird use case. A KVM sounds sort of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have 2 USB 3.0 port replicators, both hooked up to 3 separate monitors, a keyboard, a mouse and speakers. The setups on both side are totally identical.  At any given time, I can take the physical USB cable and hook up laptop 1 to setup A or B and laptop 2 to the other.  I simply want a switch device so that the laptops can be hooked up all the time and toggle between the port replicators and their corresponding peripherals.  It’s a simple true swap, I’m honestly surprised this doesn’t seem to be a more prevalent device.  It’s just a simple crossover in my mind.